# How do you write audio to the first frame with AVAssetWriter while capturing video/audio on iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, video, avassetwriter

Long story short, I am trying to implement a naive solution for streaming video from the iOS camera/microphone to a server.

I am using `AVCaptureSession` with audio and video `AVCaptureOutputs`, and then using `AVAssetWriter`/`AVAssetWriterInput` to capture video and audio in the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection` method and write the resulting video to a file.

To make this a stream, I am using an `NSTimer` to break the video files into 1 second chunks (by hot-swapping in a different `AVAssetWriter` that has a different `outputURL`) and upload these to a server over HTTP.

This is working, but the issue I'm running into is this: the beginning of the `.mp4` files appear to always be missing audio in the first frame, so when the video files are concatenated on the server (running `ffmpeg`) there is a noticeable audio skip at the intersections of these files. The video is just fine - no skipping.

[image: Blank audio]

I tried many ways of making sure there were no `CMSampleBuffers` dropped and checked their timestamps to make sure they were going to the right `AVAssetWriter`, but to no avail.

Checking the [AVCam example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` and AVCaptureLocation example with `AVAssetWriter` and it appears the files they generate do the same thing.

Maybe there is something fundamental I am misunderstanding here about the nature of audio/video files, as I'm new to video/audio capture - but thought I'd check before I tried to workaround this by learning to use `ffmpeg` as some seem to do to fragment the stream (if you have any tips on this, too, let me know!). Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you found the problem?

Comment: @PabloMartinez Sorry for the late reply on this - no I did not find a solution to this particular problem. I ended up having the AVAssetWriters overlap  (so writing to both AVAssetWriters for a few frames) and then trimming the first few frames off the resulting clip using `AVAssetExportSession`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by recording audio with a different API, Audio Queue. This seems to solve it, just need to take care of timing in order to avoid sound delay.